# Calculate Mean Opinion Score (MOS) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, math, statistics, voip

Is it possible to calculate MOS in MySQL and can somebody provide a working example using the following formula (see below and found in perl script [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ADAMBA/Algorithm-MOS-0.001/lib/Algorithm/MOS.pm)) for a timeset of 30minutes?

For the exercise data is inserted ever 5min and colums are:

```
<column>        <exampledata>
id              42
timestamp       2016-01-01 00:00:05
packets         1000
lost_perc       3
lost            30
delay_avg       35,102

id              43
timestamp       2016-01-01 00:00:10
packets         2000
lost_perc       10
lost            200
delay_avg       74,67
```

**Jitter**

```
    Sum all delay_avg records and divide by number of delay_avg records-1
```

**Effective Latency**
*Take the average latency, add jitter, but double the impact to latency then add 10 for protocol latancies.*

```
    $effective_latency = ( $delay_avg + $jitter * 2 + 10 );
```

**R-Values**
*Implement a basic curve*

```
    if ($effective_latency < 160) {
        $r_value = 93.2 - ($effective_latency / 40);
    }
    else {
        $r_value = 93.2 - ($effective_latency - 120) / 10;
    }
```

*Deduct 2.5 r_value per percentage of packet_loss*

```
   $r_value = $r_value - ($lost_perc * 2.5);
   # Convert the r_value into an MOS value.
   $MOS = 1 + 
       (0.035) *
       $r_value +
       (0.000007) *
       $r_value *
       ($r_value - 60) *
       (100 - $r_value);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `select Sum(delay_avg)/(Count(1)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

MOS is a subjective scale that you can't measure, but there are known MOS values for certain audio codecs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your jitter calculation is correct.
Jitter should mean the variaton of packet arrival times. Maybe you can calculate it like:  longest interval minus smallest interval.
The formula you specified for jitter just returns average packet delay.

Then you should be able to write some formula using the following factors:
(calculated for as small intervals as possible):

- packet loss
- average delay
- codec
- jitter

There is no any exact formula for this (as the MOS is normally found out by human experiment tests), but based on these you can get some number which will be highly correlated with the actual voice quality.

Comment: I know - that's why I pointed at the PingPlotter implementation https://www.pingman.com/kb/article/how-is-mos-calculated-in-pingplotter-pro-50.html of how it -can- be pseudo-calculated to give an impression of what quality can be expected. Will try to add the codec into the mix though. Thanks!

Comment: Just adding it in case somebody else is interested sometime..    /* MOS */
        latency = (davg + (jitter * 2) + 10) / 1000;
        if(latency < 160) {
          r_factor = 93.2 - (latency / 40);
        } else {
          r_factor = 93.2 - (latency - 120) / 10;
        }
        r_factor = r_factor - (lost * 2.5);
        mos = 1 + (0.035) * (r_factor) +
          (0.000007) * (r_factor) * ((r_factor) - 60)
          * (100 - (r_factor));